# Own class for location tracking using LocationManagerApi is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, location

I wrote a class to track the position of a smartphone. For this I use the LocationManagerAPI.
This is my class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.util.Log

class NetworkLocationTracker {
    private var latitude: Double = 0.0
    private var longitude: Double = 0.0

    private var locationManager: LocationManager
    private var locationListener: LocationListener? = null

    constructor(context: Context) {
        this.locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        this.locationListener = object : LocationListener {
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                setLatitude(location.latitude)
                setLongitude(location.longitude)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun startLocationTracking() {
        if(this.locationListener != null) {
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, this.locationListener as LocationListener)
        }
    }

    fun stopLocationTracking() {
        if (this.locationListener != null) {
            this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener as LocationListener)
            this.locationListener = null
        }
    }

    fun getLatitude(): Double {
        return this.latitude
    }

    fun getLongitude(): Double {
        return this.longitude
    }

    fun setLatitude(latitude: Double) {
        this.latitude = latitude
    }

    fun setLongitude(longitude: Double) {
        this.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use to test the class:

```
var nlt = NetworkLocationTracker(this)
nlt.startLocationTracking()
for(i in 1..10) {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    Log.d("Debug", "${nlt.getLatitude()} ${nlt.getLongitude()}")
}
nlt.stopLocationTracking()
```

When I run my test code, I only ever get the values 0.0 and 0.0 for the position.

I have activated the location service and I do not get any error messages. The permissions are handled correct also. Can someone find the error in my class and give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm going to assume you've done the basics, like ensured you have both compile time and runtime permissions checking finished.

0,0 is the default if the onLocationChanged function isn't called.  The onLocationChanged function is called on the main thread.  So if you're calling your start method on the main thread, you can't loop waiting for updates.  You need to return to the handler to actually see it be called.  This is probably your issue.  Instead of looping trying to print the values, put the print in the onLocationChanged function and wait for it to occur.  That will probably fix your code.